# python remoteconfig unable to parse file from Gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, ini

I am trying to get remoteconfig working, following this guide:
https://pypi.org/project/remoteconfig/

As a control, I have this code that works:

```
config.read('./config.ini')
for section in config:
   print(section)
```

When I put the same config file in a remote Gitlab, this code does not work:

```
from remoteconfig import config
config.read('https://myorg.org/path/repo/~/blob/app/config.ini')
for section in config:
    print(section)
```

What could I be doing wrong here? The error msg I am getting is:
`configParser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers`

So it seems like it's reaching the file path (network/connectivity OK), but not liking what's in that file or possibly the file format? The same exact file works with localconfig.

Comment: Is the project public? It's possible you're not getting the response content you're expecting. For example, if that URL requires authentication, you may be redirected to a login page, which obviously won't be a valid config file. You probably also want to use the `raw` link.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am going to use the 'gitlab' pip module and simply consume the API for the file (with private_token:
`f = project.files.get(file_path='path/file', ref='master'`